# Series solution of IVP $y' = \sqrt{1-y^{2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, solution-verification, initial-value-problems

Given the IVP 
$$ y' = \sqrt{1-y^2},\qquad y(0) = 0 \tag{1}$$
I'm looking for a solution in the form of a power series in power of $x$ about $x=0$. Particularly, I'm looking for the coefficients up to the term in $x^{3}$ in the series.

My attempt is as follows ; the given ODE $(1)$ is separable hence
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}} &= \int dx \\
\sin^{-1}(y) &= x+C,
\end{align}
given the initial condition $y(0)=0$, 
\begin{gather}
y = \sin(x+0) = \sin(x)\\
\therefore y(x) = \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^k x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \dots.
\end{gather}
Therefore, the coefficient sup to $x^3$ as requested are $\{1, -\frac13 \}$. I'm confused by two things : the simplicity of the reasoning and I'm not sure if the first coefficient is actually $0$ instead of $1$ , since the initial condition dictates the value of the initial term in a series solution (I think).

Comment: Yes, the initial term in the series is zero. There is no contradiction with the initial condition there.

Comment: Note that you don't really need to integrate, $y''=-y$ and $y'''=-y'$ and just plug $x=0$ in that to get Taylor coefficients up to  $x^3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the solution $y(x)=\sin(x)$ is obvious by inspection or by integration as you did. Note that the coefficient of $x^3$ is not $-\frac13$ but is $-\frac16$. A typo I suppose.

Are you sure that this is what is asked for ?

The question might be to find the coefficient of $x^3$ without solving the ODE, but only with series expansion :

$$y(x)=a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+O(x^4) \quad ;\quad a_0=0 \text{ because}\quad y(0)=0.$$

$$y'=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+O(x^3)$$
$$y'=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+O(x^3)=\sqrt{1-\big(a_1x+a_2x^2+O(x^3)\big)^2}$$
$$a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+O(x^3)=1-\frac12\big(a_1x+O(x^2)\big)^2=1-\frac12 a_1^2x^2+O(x^3)$$
$$(a_1-1)+2a_2x+(3a_3+\frac12 a_1^2)x^2+O(x^3)=0\quad\implies\quad
\begin{cases}
a_1=1 \\
a_2=0 \\
a_3=-\frac16 \end{cases} $$

Comment: Hey thank you, this is certainly what I was looking for , very nice reasoning to !

Comment: Hello, looking back at your solution I'm really confused about one step and was wondering if you could elaborate on that one ? Particularly line 3 to 4 i.e., $$ \sqrt{1-(a_{1}x + a_{2}x^{2} + O(x^{3}))^2} = 1- \frac12 (a_{1}x+ O(x^2))^2$$. Thank you

Comment: $$\big(a_1x+a_2x^2+O(x^3)\big)^2=a_1^2x^2+2a_1a_2x^3+O(x^4)$$

$$\sqrt{1-\big(a_1x+a_2x^2+O(x^3)\big)^2}= 1-\frac12 \big(a_1^2x^2+2a_1a_2x^3+O(x^4)\big)=1-\frac12 a_1^2x^2+O(x^3)$$

Comment: Hey , sorry for bothering again but I've asked a couple friends and we're still very confused about that step ; where does the $\frac12$ come from and how does the square root vanish ? Does this follow from some Taylor remainder properties that I haven't heard of before ?

Comment: Series expansion of square root : $$\sqrt{1+X}=1+\frac12 X-\frac18 X^2+...$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series .